# R: subset a data frame based on conditions from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Here is a problem I am trying to solve.  Say, I have two data frames like the following:

```
observations <- data.frame(id = rep(rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=5), 5),
    time = c(rep(1:5,4), rep(6:10,4), rep(11:15,4), rep(16:20,4), rep(21:25,4)),
    measurement = rnorm(100,5,7))

sampletimes <- data.frame(location = letters[1:20], 
    id = rep(1:4,5),
    time1 = rep(c(2,7,12,17,22), each=4), 
    time2 = rep(c(4,9,14,19,24), each=4))
```

They both contain a column named `id`, which links the data frames.  I want to have the `measurement`s from `observationss for which`time`is between`time1`and`time2`from the`sampletimes`data frame.  Additionally, I'd like to connect the appropriate`location` to each measurement.

I have successfully done this by converting my `sampletimes` to a wide format (i.e. all the `time1` and `time2` information in one row per entry for `id`), merging the two data frames by the `id` variable, and using conditional statements to take only instances when the `time` falls between at least one of the time intervals in the row, and then assigning `location` to the appropriate measurement.

However, I have around 2 million rows in `observations` and doing this takes a really long time.  I'm looking for a better way where I can keep the data in long format.  The example dataset is very simple, but in reality, my data contains variable numbers of intervals and locations per `id`.

For our example, the data frame I would hope to get back would be as follows:

```
id time measurement letters[1:20]
1    3  10.5163892             a
2    3   5.5774119             b
3    3  10.5057060             c
4    3  14.1563179             d
1    8   2.2653761             e
2    8  -1.0905546             f
3    8  12.7434161             g
4    8  17.6129261             h
1   13  10.9234673             i
2   13   1.6974481             j
3   13  -0.3664951             k
4   13  13.8792198             l
1   18   6.5038847             m
2   18   1.2032935             n
3   18  15.0889469             o
4   18   0.8934357             p
1   23   3.6864527             q
2   23   0.2404074             r
3   23  11.6028766             s
4   23  20.7466908             t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not efficient , but do the job :

```
 subset(merge(observations,sampletimes), time > time1 & time < time2)
        id time measurement location time1 time2
    11   1    3    3.180321        a     2     4
    47   1    8    6.040612        e     7     9
    83   1   13   -5.999317        i    12    14
    99   1   18    2.689414        m    17    19
    125  1   23   12.514722        q    22    24
    137  2    8    4.420679        f     7     9
    141  2    3   11.492446        b     2     4
    218  2   13    6.672506        j    12    14
    234  2   18   12.290339        n    17    19
    250  2   23   12.610828        r    22    24
    251  3    3    8.570984        c     2     4
    267  3    8   -7.112291        g     7     9
    283  3   13    6.287598        k    12    14
    360  3   23   11.941846        s    22    24
    364  3   18   -4.199001        o    17    19
    376  4    3    7.133370        d     2     4
    402  4    8   13.477790        h     7     9
    418  4   13    3.967293        l    12    14
    454  4   18   12.845535        p    17    19
    490  4   23   -1.016839        t    22    24
```

**EDIT**

Since you have more than 5 millions rows, you should give a try to a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
OBS <- data.table(observations)
SAM <- data.table(sampletimes)
merge(OBS,SAM,allow.cartesian=TRUE,by='id')[time > time1 & time < time2]
```

Comment: Initially, this solution worked.  However, when I increased the size of the observations data frame to roughly 5 million rows, it did not work.  I got the following error: `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`.  Every other command I tried produced the same error message.

Comment: @Frank I edit my solution to provide a data.table solution. let me know if you get the same error.

Comment: My times were in POSIXlt format, and it didn't work, as `data.table` doesn't support POSIXlt.  Once I converted my time columns to POSIXct, it worked.

Comment: @Frank works for the 5 millions rows? better to use `POSIXct`, it is a numerric. `POSIXlt` is a list , use it only if you want to subset your datetimes (get hour, days,months..)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proposal with `merge`:

```
# merge both data frames
dat <- merge(observations, sampletimes, by = "id")
# extract valid rows
dat2 <- dat[dat$time > dat$time1 & dat$time < dat$time2, seq(4)]
# sort
dat2[order(dat2$time, dat2$id), ]
```

The result:

```
    id time measurement location
11   1    3    7.086246        a
141  2    3    6.893162        b
251  3    3   16.052627        c
376  4    3   -6.559494        d
47   1    8   11.506810        e
137  2    8   10.959782        f
267  3    8   11.079759        g
402  4    8   11.082015        h
83   1   13    5.584257        i
218  2   13   -1.714845        j
283  3   13  -11.196792        k
418  4   13    8.887907        l
99   1   18    1.656558        m
234  2   18   16.573179        n
364  3   18    6.522298        o
454  4   18    1.005123        p
125  1   23   -1.995719        q
250  2   23   -6.676464        r
360  3   23   10.514282        s
490  4   23    3.863357        t
```