# Subset a data frame based on matching columns to rows - R

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a large data frame based on matching IDs from another data frame. I read the answer to this question posted:

[R: subset a data frame based on conditions from another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165123/r-subset-a-data-frame-based-on-conditions-from-another-data-frame)

However, my data differs from this in that for one of my data sets I have the linker ID set up in a column, and in the other, it goes across rows

> Data set 1
>
> `*ID* time stat`
>   `*1*  3.21  6`
>   `*4* 7.9 3`
>   ...
>
> Data set 2
>
> `*ID 1 2 4* ...`
>   `y yellow brown yellow`
>   `z 3 5 2`
>   `a yes yes no`

What I ultimately would like to get is a data frame where I only have the data from data set 2 that has a matching sample ID in data set 1. So in this example:

> `*ID 1 4* ...`
>   `y yellow yellow`
>   `z 3 2`
>   `a yes no`

Any help is much appreciated.

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is

```
newDf<-df2[,df2[1,]%in%df1[,1]]
```

where df1[,1] is the data set with the id column in column position 1, and df2[1,] is the dataset with the id column in row position 1.

```
df2[1,]
#[1] 1 3 4

df1[,1]
#[1] 1 4

df2[1,]%in%df1[,1]
#[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE
```