# R - Subset a dataframe based on condition from another dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, merge, subset

I have a question which is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165123/r-subset-a-data-frame-based-on-conditions-from-another-data-frame) post but it is not working for me because of a slight change in the condition.

I have 2 dataframes which looks like:

```
> effect
  V1        V2 V3
1 G1 activates G2
2 G3     stops G4
3 G5 activates G6
4 G6     stops G7

> expression
  V1 V2
1 G1  1
2 G2  0
3 G3  1
4 G4  0
5 G5  1
6 G6  1
7 G7  1
```

I want to keep only those rows in `effect` dataframe which fulfills following condition:

- if `effect$V2 == activates` then `expression$V2` should be 1 where
  `effect$V3` and `expression$V1` are the same
- if `effect$V2 == stops` then `expression$V2` should be 0 where
  `effect$V3` and `expression$V1` are the same

According to this criteria I will get on this results:

```
> results
  V1        V2 V3
1 G3     stops G4
2 G5 activates G6
```

Because this is consistent with the given conditions such that for the first row the `V2=stops` and `expression$V2` for the `G4` is `0`.

Similarly, for row2 `V2=activates`and `expression$V2` for the `G6` is `1`

The structure of the dataframes are given below. Any help will be much appreciated.

df1:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("G1", "G3", "G5", 
"G6"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("activates", 
"stops"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("G2", 
"G4", "G6", "G7"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", 
"G4", "G5", "G6", "G7"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I have figured out the answer to my own question. If admin wants, they can delete this question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer for this. It is:

```
ab <- merge(effect, expression, by.x = "V3", by.y = "V1")
cd <- subset(ab, V2.x == "activates" & V2.y == 1 | V2.x == "stops" & V2.y == 0)
results <- cd[,c(2,3,1)]
> results
  V1      V2.x V3
2 G3     stops G4
3 G5 activates G6
```

Comment: You could combine that all into one step and avoid storing the in-between data.frames with `subset(merge(effect, expression, by.x = "V3", by.y = "V1"), V2.x == "activates" & V2.y == 1 | V2.x == "stops" & V2.y == 0)[, c(2, 3, 1)]`